# how get just user with roles in mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I want get **just in Role users**  in mvc, I tried everything. As you know `AspNetUserRoles` is a mapping table (many-to-many), so it's not generated in EDMX (by design, it does not have primary key). Also we can't use **Role table**(**?**). Please consider my model in view.

Here is my last try:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Roles()
    {
        var list = context.Users.Include(u => u.Roles);
        var user = new List<ApplicationUser>();
        foreach(var u in list)
        {
            if(u.Roles!= null)
            {
                user.Add(u);
            }
        }     
        return View(user);
    }
```

and here is my view:

```
    @model IEnumerable<Site.Models.ApplicationUser>
      @{
        Layout = null;
       }

       <h2>List of users with Roles:</h2>
       <table class="table">
      <tr>
       <th>
           @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
       </th>
       <th>
          @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
       </th>
       <th>
          @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Roles)
      </th>
   </tr>
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Roles)
        </th>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
  }
   </table>
```

Comment: So what is the problem ? You are not getting users with any role ?

Comment: i want get just in Role users but this code get all users.

Comment: what if you change `if(u.Roles!= null)` into `if(u.Roles.Any())`?

Comment: " just in Role users" you mean  just in a specific role?  then which role? you are not specifying any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one out:

```
    var usersList = new List<ApplicationUser>();
    foreach (ApplicationUser user in UserManager.Users)
    {
        var roles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);
        if(roles.contains("Admin"))
        {
            usersList.Add(user);
        }
    }
```

This one should only return users who has Admin role. I hope it helps.

Comment: So maybe all users has at least a role ? ;) Have You tried debugging, what is being returned when user does not have any role ?

Comment: i have just admin role in my site and in AspNetRoles table in database

Comment: Please tell me what happens when You are trying to debug Your application :)

Comment: maybe it is default in asp

Comment: the view shows all users and in front of admin user in Role place it shows the admin user key

Comment: Well but it works fine for me, just try for example changing `roles.Any()` to `roles.Contains("Admin")` it should return all users with Admin role. It is just for test.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should query based on a specific role.
Because if later on you add more roles , your application will become buggy.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Roles()
    {
        var user= context.Users.Include(u => u.Roles).Where(u=>u.Roles.Any(r=>r.Name=="RoleName")).ToList();
        return View(user);
    }
```